# Upload images by auto executing script to google cloud storage from server

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I want to upload images from my sever to the google cloud storage.I don know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From your tags, I'm guessing you're using Google AppEngine with PHP. Documentation on how to upload to Google Cloud Storage using AppEngine with PHP is available here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

The basic example:

```
$options = [ "gs" => [ "Content-Type" => "text/plain" ]];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents("gs://my_bucket/hello.txt", "Hello", 0, $ctx);
```

Check out the section "Uploading to Google Cloud Storage" for more information.